# glusterfs centos 7 - won't start

Tags: glusterfs

I am attempting to bring up a glusterfs cluster on two nodes. The only thing that might be a little complicated about my setup is that I have two nodes connected to each other through a cross connect cable, hence there is no switch. The way I have my private IP addresses set up on each node is as follows. **Notice that there is no default gateway for the 10.0.0.0/24 network, which might be giving me problems getting this to work**:

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ uname -a
Linux node1.synctrading 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 03:04:26 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[idf@node1 ~]$ 

[idf@node2 ~]$ uname -a
Linux node2.synctrading 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[idf@node2 ~]$
```

Each node appears to have a "config" directory but I don't remember touching any of these file:

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ ls /etc/glusterfs/
glusterd.vol                glusterfs-logrotate       gluster-rsyslog-7.2.conf  logger.conf.example
glusterfs-georep-logrotate  gluster-rsyslog-5.8.conf  group-virt.example
[idf@node1 ~]$
```

I have one drive in each node mounted on sdb as my "bricks"

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  6.9G   44G  14% /
devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G  140K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G  9.1M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb                 932G   33M  932G   1% /data/brick1
/dev/mapper/centos-home  408G  4.9G  403G   2% /home
/dev/sda1                497M  162M  336M  33% /boot
10.0.0.61:/var/nfsshare   50G   43G  7.7G  85% /mnt/nfs/var/nfsshare

[idf@node2 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   43G  7.7G  85% /
devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G  140K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G  9.1M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb                 932G   33M  932G   1% /data/brick1
/dev/mapper/centos-home  408G   17G  391G   5% /home
/dev/sda1                497M  133M  365M  27% /boot
[idf@node2 ~]$
```

My networking is set up as follows:

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ more /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR0=10.0.0.60
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
PREFIX0=24
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=enp1s0f1
ONBOOT=yes

[idf@node2 ~]$ more /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR0=10.0.0.61
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
PREFIX0=24
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=enp1s0f1
ONBOOT=yes
```

My hosts file looks like this

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1   glusterfs2
10.0.0.61   glusterfs1
10.0.0.60   glusterfs2

[idf@node2 ~]$ more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1   glusterfs1
10.0.0.61   glusterfs1
10.0.0.60   glusterfs2
```

I have added these firewall rules to each node:

```
sudo iptables  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 111         -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 111         -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 2049        -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 24007       -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 38465:38469 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 49152       -j ACCEPT
```

The output of `ip route`

```
[idf@node2 ~]$ ip route
default via xxx.xxx.xx.xx dev enp1s0f0  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp1s0f1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.61  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev ib0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1  metric 150 
[idf@node2 ~]$ 

[idf@node1 ~]$ ip route
default via xxx.xxx.xx.xx dev enp1s0f0  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp1s0f1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.60  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev ib0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2  metric 150 
[idf@node1 ~]$
```

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network` is empty

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ sudo more /etc/sysconfig/network
# Created by anaconda
[idf@node1 ~]$
```

When I run

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ service glusterd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  glusterd.service
glusterd.service - GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/glusterd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2015-05-09 23:32:06 EDT; 26min ago
  Process: 5561 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5562 (glusterd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/glusterd.service
           \u2514\u25005562 /usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid

[idf@node1 ~]$ sudo gluster peer probe glusterfs1
peer probe: failed: Probe returned with unknown errno 107
[idf@node1 ~]$
```

The contents of /var/log/glusterfs log file:

```
[idf@node1 ~]$ sudo tail -f /var/log/glusterfs/etc-glusterfs-glusterd.vol.log
[2015-05-10 04:22:43.599679] I [mem-pool.c:545:mem_pool_destroy] 0-management: size=588 max=0 total=0
[2015-05-10 04:22:43.599693] I [mem-pool.c:545:mem_pool_destroy] 0-management: size=124 max=0 total=0
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.944473] I [glusterd-handler.c:1015:__glusterd_handle_cli_probe] 0-glusterd: Received CLI probe req node2 24007
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.945762] I [glusterd-handler.c:3165:glusterd_probe_begin] 0-glusterd: Unable to find peerinfo for host: node2 (24007)
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.985030] I [rpc-clnt.c:969:rpc_clnt_connection_init] 0-management: setting frame-timeout to 600
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.990323] I [glusterd-handler.c:3098:glusterd_friend_add] 0-management: connect returned 0
**[2015-05-10 04:28:53.990605] E [socket.c:2276:socket_connect_finish] 0-management: connection to 10.0.0.61:24007 failed (No route to host)**
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.990665] I [MSGID: 106004] [glusterd-handler.c:4365:__glusterd_peer_rpc_notify] 0-management: Peer 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, in Establishing Connection state, has disconnected from glusterd.
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.990849] I [mem-pool.c:545:mem_pool_destroy] 0-management: size=588 max=0 total=0
[2015-05-10 04:28:53.990867] I [mem-pool.c:545:mem_pool_destroy] 0-management: size=124 max=0 total=0
```

on either node I this error: **I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is it that I don't have a default gw for the 10.0.0.0/24 network?**

Comment: Why do you call the machines node1 and node2 and then refer to glusterfs1 and glusterfs2 in /etc/hosts?

Comment: I can change that pretty easily. Doing that now.

Comment: same error. What is strange is that it gives this error no matter what I type in, e.g, 'sudo gluster peer probe random' also gives an error

Comment: Note this line in the log file (** above): [2015-05-10 04:28:53.990605] E [socket.c:2276:socket_connect_finish] 0-management: connection to 10.0.0.61:24007 failed (No route to host)

Comment: I think when there is no switch, the FW is the gateway. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Post the output of sudo mii-tool, ip link, ip route, try pinging one box from the other

Comment: it seems network is ok, maybe 24007 is UDP too?

Comment: ip route is already given in the original post. I added the rest at the EDIT section. The first thing I did was to make sure I could ping both servers from each other, both by raw IP address and by host name.

Comment: my first test would be to disable the firewall

Comment: Andre that appears to be problem. I said 'sudo iptables -I INPUT -p all -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT' and it works. Thanks.